# run java jar file on HP-UX as UNIX as "os.name"

Tags: java, unix, operating-system, hp-ux

I need to execute a jar file on HP-UX that I am not supposed to modify.

I unpacked it using jd-gui and found out that I am failing cause in java there is a condition to check the os, leading to different directions for win, macos, freebds, openbds, gnu and so on.

I am quite sure everything would work if I would be able to make my unix command line reply freebds or openbds to the java call

`System.getProperty("os.name")`

once executed from a jar file like:

`java -jar myjar.jar`

is there a way to achieve this? some kind of compatibility mode or a way to preset that parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-D` switch to specify system properties. In my experiment this (unexpectedly) even worked with pre-defined ones like `os.name`. Therefore this should work:

```
java -Dos.name=linux -jar myjar.jar
```